# Display webview's content in textview android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have extracted html files from `.epub` extension. When i tried to load data in string i couldn't load entire content. I couldn't find out what the problem is in loading web content in string.

The following is the way i am trying to load data in string.

The html file has  this much tags. Only  much stored in string. Can anyone please tell me what the problem might be?

I tried to store the string in `textview`. Still i am having same problem.

```
String displayString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("display");
if(displayString != null)
            webView.loadData(displayString,"text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

Comment: epub is not html

Comment: when extracting epub, html files are seen

Comment: how does the question relate to `javascript`?

Comment: I tried editting the tag bu it's not changing to android